# PHP print_r used twice, only working once, can't figure out why

Tags: php, pdo

I'm learning to connect to my database and create/read/update/delete information from different tables.  Currently I'm using PDO instead of mysqli because I'm having an easier time with prepared statements.  What I'm trying to do right now doesn't actually have any value, I just want to know WHY this is happening.  Here's my code:

```
//pdo connection
try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host={$db_host};dbname={$db_name}", $db_user, $db_pass);
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  //READ FROM DB
  $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM objects where ID = :id');
  $stmt->execute(array(':id'=>8));

  print_r($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ));

  while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    $results[] = $row;
  }

  print_r($results);

  } catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
  }
```

Now, what's happening is that if I `print_r` in this order then only the first `print_r` works and vice versa (assuming I also move the while loop with the `print_r($results)` statement.  Why is it that I am only allowed to do this once and whichever is first negates the second?

EDIT: Clarification.

Comment: So after emptying a bottle of beer into a glass, you are trying to fill a mug from the same bottle, aren't you?

Comment: You're done looping, there are no more results.

Comment: I get that I'm basically doing the same thing twice, what I guess I don't understand is why it can't happen twice.  So basically after running `$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)` I can't run that again without doing another execute or something?  I don't quite understand.

Comment: Try to understand (or just realize) how (and WHY) that `while($row = whatever_fetch()) {` thingy works. This is the key.

Comment: or at least try to make two identical `print_r($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ));` calls. May be it could make you think.

Comment: Ok, so I see that I would have to run the `execute` method again to get the `fetch` to work again.  So apparently `fetch` empties `$stmt` is what I'm understanding?

Comment: Yes, check http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php instead.

Comment: if you need the data again store it in a variable, dont query the db twice. remove the first `$stmt->fetch` ... keep the loop then you can use `$results` as many times as you want

Comment: `"So apparently fetch empties $stmt"`. Try to run a query that returns more than 1 row and run the same 2 fetches. You'll have your mind blown away!